# print key of highest value in map

Tags: javascript

I have created the following map:

```
(function getLakes() {
    let lakes = new Map ([['Caspian Sea', 560], ['Tarn Hows', 53], ['Crater Lake', 324], ['Lake Tanganyika', 803], ['Lake Vostok', 546],
    ['Lake Baikal', 897]]);
    let fathom = 1.829;

    console.log("The deepest lake is " +  Math.max(...lakes.values())*fathom);
    })();
```

Additionally to logging the value, I would also like to log the key, so that I end up with the following, additional line:
"The deepest lake is Lake Baikal."

I am not sure how to make this work - does anyone have an idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Spread the Map and use `Array.find()` on the entries (`[key, value]` pairs. Use destructuring to get the the name (key) of the lake.

```js
const lakes = new Map([
  ['Caspian Sea', 560],
  ['Tarn Hows', 53],
  ['Crater Lake', 324],
  ['Lake Tanganyika', 803],
  ['Lake Vostok', 546],
  ['Lake Baikal', 897]
]);

const fathom = 1.829;
const max = Math.max(...lakes.values());
const [lake] = [...lakes].find(([, v]) => v === max);

console.log(`The deepest lake is ${max * fathom}`);
console.log(`The deepest lake is ${lake}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write own custom logic instead of using `Math.max` Refer below code sample.

```
let lakes = new Map ([['Caspian Sea', 560], ['Tarn Hows', 53], ['Crater Lake', 324], ['Lake Tanganyika', 803], ['Lake Vostok', 546],
    ['Lake Baikal', 897]]);
let fathom = 1.829;
let maxValue,maxKey;
for (let [key, value] of lakes.entries()) {
  if(!maxValue || maxValue < value){
     maxValue = value;
     maxKey = key;
  }
}
console.log("The deepest lake is " + maxKey + ' = ' + (maxValue*fathom) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the entries:

```
 const [lake, depth] = [...lakes.entries()]
   .reduce((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? a : b);

 console.log(`Lake ${lake} has the depth ${depth}`);
```